# Can you run an asp.net MVC web app inside an iframe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

My company has an asp.net mvc app that they want to run inside another webapp (probably React right now). If I just put the app inside an iframe( no react, just a static html page). It will render the inital page ok, but the first partial control fails because it cannot find the session keys.

```
    public virtual UserModel LoggedInUser
    {
        get 
        {    
            return Session[SessionKeys.LOGGED_IN_USER] as UserModel; //THIS FAILS. No keys in the session
        }

        set 
        {
            Session[SessionKeys.LOGGED_IN_USER] = value; 
        }
```

I'm not too suprised by this, but I don't know of a workaround. I tried a cookieless session to no avail (the app didn't run even outside the iframe). Would it help if the containing webpage was another mvc app? It seems the only option is to port all the razor pages over to react and refactor the controllers to not return view.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may publish your application in another domain. thereby, you can serve it in the iframe. If you want to match with these two applications to use login, session, etc. then you can use Uniqidentifier in your query string so your MVC application would know which user sent the request